# Symfony2 Use logger in listener

Tags: php, symfony, logging, service

I want to use Monolog to write logs from a listener in a Symfony2 application.

My listener is defined this way:

```
use Monolog\Logger;

class CalendarEventListener
{

    private $logger;

    public function __construct(Logger $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function loadEvents(CalendarEvent $calendarEvent)
    {

        $this->logger->info('test');

        ...

    }
}
```

And this is in my file src/CRMBundle/Resources/config/services.xml:

```
<services>
    <service id="crmbundle.calendar_listener" class="CRMBundle\EventListener\CalendarEventListener">
        <argument type="service" id="logger" />
        <tag name="monolog.logger" event="calendar.load_events" method="loadEvents" />
    </service>
</services>
```

But nothing is written in the log file when the listener is called.

Comment: I would also check your monolog settings in your config and config_{env} files.  Some configurations have a log level that needs to be hit before anything is written.  So if it's set to something higher than debug, info logs may not ever show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing two different tags together. The `monolog.logger` tag, allows you to use a custom logging channel. Listening to an event is a completely separate matter. use the `kernel.event_listener` tag name instead. You can see a full list of tags [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html). Also if `calendar.load_events` is a custom event be sure to dispatch it somewhere using the core event dispatcher: `@event_dispatcher`.